# The most reliable way to download data over HTTP

Tags: http, high-load, http-status-code-503

What is the most reliable choice of programming language / technology to perform requests and, most important, retrieve correct and full responses from an HTTP server which is under very heavy load, often yielding HTTP 503 Service Unavailable or just taking too much time to respond. What is the way to retrive data from such server which will pretty much guarantee, that all data will be downloaded properly and in fastest possible time?

Comment: Should your requests be considered "privileged" / "more important" than all the other load that the HTTP server has? Otherwise, the best way is to keep trying / try again when the load isn't as high.

Comment: I need to get the response ANYWAY, I just cannot try later when load is not high.

Comment: My question was, do you have any amount of control over the server you're sending requests to (as in, you can tell them to favor your requests)

Comment: oh sorry, now I see what you mean. No, I have no control over the server. My application appears just as an usual user of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Given the situation where your application has no special treatment from the server, you will have to just keep trying until the server gives you the page.

Keep in mind that this may be a very bad idea during actual server outages (not just high-load) so you may want to report failure to the user and tell them to try again later.